# Show that $U_{k}(n)$ is a subgroup of $U(n)$ where $U_{k}(n) = \{x \in U(n) : x \text{ mod } k = 1\}$ and $k | n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $U_{k}(n)$ is a subgroup of $U(n)$ where $U_{k}(n) = \{x \in U(n) : x \text{ mod } k = 1\}$ and $k | n$ where $U(n)$ is the set that includes $1$ and all number less than $n$ that do not divide $n$.

I am trying to prove this by showing that $(\forall a,b \in U_{k}(n))(ab^{-1} \in U_k(n)).$

I know that if $a,b$ are in $U_k(n)$ then $a$ mod $k = 1$ and $b$ mod $k = 1$, but from here I can't make any progress towards showing $ab^{-1}$ mod $k = 1$.

Comment: Could you define what $U(k)$ is?

Comment: $U(n)$ is presumably the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z_n$

Comment: Fixed the mistake.

Comment: The notation here is a bit weird, because the elements of $U(n)$ are usually not thought of as integers, so reducing $\bmod k$ can only make sense when $k|n$.